# Cannot access to web server, but can ssh to it

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apache-httpd, ping

I have a Ubuntu server but there are some weird things I can't understand.

I cannot ping to the server via IP address, but I can ssh to it. I can access to apache server inside the server via command line, but I cannot acccess in my Windows's browser.

What kind of setting I need to check now?

Comment: Check your iptables firewall rules, you might be blocking port 80/443, as well as ICMP ping, but allowing ssh.  If you don't have a firewall running, it might be your routing table, but that doesn't explain everything.

Comment: One other possibility is that Apache isn't listening on the correct network interface, but that's highly unlikely if this is a new install.

Comment: @jsbillings, routing tables direct traffic at the IP level, if you can reach the machine at the IP level (via _direct_ ssh) then you can reach it by ICMP (ping, ...) and HTTP/HTTPS unless something filters that out on the way (or at the destination).

Comment: Some cloud providers block ICMP (for example, [Amazon Web Services does by default](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145#18)).

Answer (score 8):

You can debug the issue using the following tools:

1. Run `wireshark` or `tcpdump` and check whether the HTTP request is reaching to the server or not.
2. Use `tcptraceroute`

   `$ tcptraceroute "webserver-ip" 80`
3. It can be the case that the webserver is listening only on localhost(127.0.0.1) instead of listening on all interfaces(0.0.0.0)

   `$ sudo netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN`
4. Check the iptables rules using

   `$ sudo iptables -nvL`
5. Check the status of SELinux which also acts as firewall.

   `$ sudo sestatus`

Answer (score 2):

1. You might have firewall rules blocking access. Check the output of `iptables -L`. Maybe everything is blocked except ssh.
2. The services might not be listening on the right interfaces or ports. Check the output of `netstat -ntl`.

If these commands don't help figuring it out, then please add their output in your question. Also add the output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue too. Here are some outputs from the above commands

```
# netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          19239      2490/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          19149      2475/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18616      1241/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20281      2487/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          19238      2490/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      91         19311      1247/java
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          19237      2490/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          163453     4050/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      91         19310      1247/java
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          19479      1282/vsftpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18618      1241/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          20282      2487/master
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          19236      2490/smbd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      91         20467      1247/java

# netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

IP Tables output:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root@localhost etc]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_internal (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). OR You can always [ask a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)  by follwing guidelines given in [ask].

Comment: no it doesn't answer the question but it offers more information regarding the issue. The OP did not add any significant information to his(her) post therefore I am. I figured out what my issue was. I had not allowed the ports to go through the firewall. I should have done this: firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent (for http) and then the reload command (firewall-cmd  --reload)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow certain ports or services like http by using firewalld.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http && firewall-cmd --reload
```